# Nifi - set one variable based on another variable

Tags: variables, apache-nifi, evaluate

[image]I have an evaluateJsonPath processor that sets a variable based on Json content. Based on the value the variable is set to, I want to set the value of another variable. So,

```
if variableA = "cat" then
   variableB = "meow"

if variableA = "dog" then
   variableB = "woof"
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [UpdateAttribute](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-update-attribute-nar/1.7.1/org.apache.nifi.processors.attributes.UpdateAttribute/additionalDetails.html) processor's Advanced usage.

Check the variable value using [Nifi Expression language](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/expression-language-guide.html#equals) **`equals`** function and add the variable to the flowfile.

Refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/141774/how-to-generate-a-variable-under-conditions-for-an.html) link for in detailed configuring/usage of UpdateAttribute processor.

Comment: I updated my post with a capture of my updateAttribute processor. The sound.name attribute is not getting picked up by my downstream processor which is an InvokeHTTP processor. sound.name is appended to the "remote url' value like this - http://host:port/${sound.name}.

Comment: @sotn, Make sure **`animal.name`** attribute have **`cat`** value (all attribute name and values are case sensitive), if these value don't match then update attribute processor don't add `sound.name` attribute. Please read about flowfile policy documentation(by placing cursor on `?` mark sign after Flowfile Policy) to choose correct policy.

Comment: I added q Logattribute processor and I see the rule is being processed right. For some reason InvokeHttp processor is not able to parse the EL ${sound.name} in the remote URL property.